# can't run app with MSVC 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015, windows-10-mobile

I'm using MSVC 2015 on Windows 10 with one of the [sample apps](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/CameraGetPreviewFrame).  When I choose `Build->Deploy` I get this error:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       Error : DEP0001 : Unexpected Error: Package type matching the cpu 'ARMV4I' of the device not found in package 'EB22551A-7F66-465F-B53F-E5ABA0C0574E'    CameraGetPreviewFrame
```

I have a Lumia plugged in with USB.  I can also use `WinAppDeployCmd` to put the app onto the phone from the command-line.  But not with MSVC.

Any ideas on how to debug this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still don't know why this was happening, but I figured out a workaround.

I had originally installed Visual Studio 2015 on Windows 7, which I later upgraded to Windows 10.  On a hunch, I uninstalled and reinstalled Visual Studio 2015 and *now its working*.  I think the OS upgrade hosed something in Visual Studio 2015 related to deploying apps.